# Why I cant assign new value for string in array?

Tags: javascript

In each word from string, every even indexed chars in each word should be upper cased.

Example: "This is a sample" -> "ThIs Is A SaMpLe"

I know that it's not the best solution to solve this problem but I want to understand why the last assignment doesn't work.

```
function toWeirdCase(string) {
const arr = string.toLowerCase().split(' ')

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j += 2) {
        let temp = arr[i][j]                        // temp = t, i, i

        temp = temp.toUpperCase()                   // temp = T, I, I

        arr[i][j] = temp                           // arr[i][j] = t, i, i but why not T, I, I
    }
}
return arr.join(' ')
}

console.log(toWeirdCase('This is'))
```

Comment: Strings are immutable

Comment: `arr` is an array of strings, therefore `arr[i]` is a string and `arr[i][j] = temp` attempts to change a character in a string but in JavaScript the strings are immutable. In order to solve your assignment you can build the scrambled value into a new string (let's name it `mixed`, by appending one character at a time (`mixed = mixed + temp.toUpperCase()`) then, in the outer `for` put `mixed` back in `arr[i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr` is an array of strings, therefore `arr[i]` is a string and `arr[i][j] = temp` attempts to change a character in a string but in JavaScript the strings are immutable.

It is explained in the [JavaScript documentation of strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Character%20access):

> When using bracket notation for character access, attempting to delete or assign a value to these properties will not succeed. The properties involved are neither writable nor configurable.

In order to solve your assignment you can build the scrambled value into a new string (let's name it `mixed`, by appending one character at a time (`mixed = mixed + temp.toUpperCase()`) then, in the outer `for` put `mixed` back in `arr[i]`:

```js
const arr = str.toLowerCase().split(' ')

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let mixed = '';
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        let temp = arr[i][j]
        // Turn to uppercase the characters on even positions
        if (j % 2 === 0) {
            temp = temp.toUpperCase()
        }

        mixed = mixed + temp
    }
    // Put the processed word back into the array
    arr[i] = mixed
}
```

Comment: Ohh yea, that explains everything. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because strings in Javascript don't work this way (like arrays). Instead of doing `arr[i][j] = temp` you can do

```
const str = arr[i]
arr[i] = str.substr(0, j) + str[j].toUppercase() + str.substr(j + 1);
```